# How to disable TLS 1.0 in NGINX?

Tags: ssl, nginx, configuration, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

On the `server` level in nginx.conf I have:

```
ssl_protocols  TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
```

but no matter what when I run:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -tls1
```

I get a valid connection for TLS 1.0. SSLLabs puts the nginx setup for the site as an A but with TLS 1.0 .

```
root@qa-ebd:~# openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -Wa,--noexecstack -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -O3 -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DRC4_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/openssl"
root@qa-ebd:~# 
root@qa-ebd:~# 
root@qa-ebd:~# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.10.2
built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/opt/nginx  --with-http_ssl_module   --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module  --with-http_stub_status_module --with-pcre
```

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/704376/disable-tls-1-0-in-nginx/704382#704382

Comment: I've read this article and it took me three hours. Tried many times, but failed.

Comment: @jww - I have solved this problem. A browser receives the default server’s certificate.Thanks.

Comment: @WeiYu how did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Open nginx configuration file (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) and add below line in http section :

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

This will disable TLS1.0 for all applications in that server. You can test with the following openssl command:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tls1
```

You should be getting output something like :

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
```

Comment: Did it like you said and indeed the output from `openssl s_client...` command reports that no connection can be made. However if I plug my website into [SSL-Labs's SSL-Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), it reports that TLS 1.0 is enabled. Thoughts?

Comment: @RaduMurzea Do you have multiple servers installed like Nginx & Apache on same machine?

Comment: @idrisjafer Thanks for your answer, I discovered the issue. Apparently we have a proxy between our server and the Internet, which is also managing the SSL settings. So yeah...

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:
Since my nginx server hosted 3 applications, I had to set

```
ssl_protocols  TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

in each of the applications.

The change will not be reflected if this is specified in the particular application that is under consideration. Instead, changing it in all the applications running on that server will be the solution. After this, the following error will be received when TLSv1.0 handshake is negotiated with the server.

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1526041526
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```